# Obtener y sobreescribir una linea de texto en un JTextArea

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

Tengo un `JTextArea` al que agrego texto y con un `KeyListener` al presionar la tecla <kbd>INTRO</kbd> deseo obtener la última linea escrita en el `JTextArea` y reemplazar esa misma linea por otro texto al evaluarse su contenido.

El evento `KeyListener` ya esta implementado y ya detecta la tecla <kbd>INTRO</kbd>.

quien me ayuda??

EL CODIGO:

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
  ini.txtdoc.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
    if(ini.txtdoc.getText().length()>0 && ke.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
      //aqui el codigo que necesito
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Podrías poner el código de lo que tienes para que te podamos ayudar?

Comment: acabo de agregar el codigo